# Simplest way to parse html tag objective c

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, html-parsing

In one of my ios project i am getting img tag as url of image. Now i have to get the href from the img tag.

What is the best and simplest solution.

here is the result i am getting from the result

```
<img src=\"http://www.shareatalent.com/wp-content/uploads/avatars/103533/103533-bpfull.jpg\" class=\"avatar user-103533-avatar avatar-450 photo\" width=\"450\" height=\"450\" alt=\"Profile photo of sb\" />
```

The result should be

```
http://www.shareatalent.com/wp-content/uploads/avatars/103533/103533-bpfull.jpg
```

Comment: Use NSRegularExpression

Comment: Use TFHpple. for more: [how-to-parse-html-on-ios](http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios), Thomas Kilian idea is much better since you do not have to import files coz you are only parsing single element.

Comment: [Objective-C-HMTL-Parser](https://github.com/zootreeves/Objective-C-HMTL-Parser) is wrapper class for parsing HTML text which might help you.

Answer (score 0):

Add this Library https://github.com/volodg/HTMLParser to your project and also add libxml2 and libxml2.2 to your project  then add this to your parse action(ex buttonaction):

```
#import "HTMLparser.h"
 NSError *error = nil;
NSString *html = @"<img src=\"http://www.shareatalent.com/wp-content/uploads/avatars/103533/103533-bpfull.jpg\" class=\"avatar user-103533-avatar avatar-450 photo\" width=\"450\" height=\"450\" alt=\"Profile photo of sb\" />
";
HTMLParser *parser = [[HTMLParser alloc] initWithString:html error:&error];

if (error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
    return;
}

HTMLNode *bodyNode = [parser body];


NSArray *spanNodes = [bodyNode findChildTags:@"img"];

for (HTMLNode *spanNode in spanNodes) {
    if ([[spanNode getAttributeNamed:@"class"] isEqualToString:@"avatar user-103533-avatar avatar-450 photo"]) {
        NSLog(@"%@", [spanNode getAttributeNamed:@"src"]); //Gives The Image URL
    }
}
```

Comment: The link to https://github.com/volodg/HTMLParser is no longer valid.

Answer (score -1):

There is plenty of functionality while converting from `HTML` to `NSAttributeString`. but i will suggest tutorial that help you to accomplish basic functionality like color change, Font change, add link, add inline image.

[Convert HTML string to NSAttributeString](http://www.raywenderlich.com/4147/core-text-tutorial-for-ios-making-a-magazine-app)

Hope this help you.